# Getting list of notification vibrate patterns supported programmatically

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am currently using the following code to get the list of notification sounds supported programmatically.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getVibratePatterns(Activity curActivity) {
    RingtoneManager manager = new RingtoneManager(curActivity);
    manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Cursor cursor = manager.getCursor();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //  String id = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
        //  String uri = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX);
        String name = cursor.getString((RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX));
        list.add(name);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Is it possible to similarly get the list of supported vibration patterns for notifications (if available)?

**EDIT**: This set of values is what I am after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe such thing exists (though I'm glad to be proven wrong).

That list you see might wired to patterns pre-defined by the developer which then used to supply the `setVibrate()` call in `NotificationBuilder`. Since `setVibrate()` accepts `long[]` as its parameter to determine the vibration pattern, I think it's pretty trivial to achieve your desired result.

You can learn more in the documentation for [`NotificationBuilder#setVibrate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setVibrate(long[])) and the [`Vibrator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class.

Comment: Even if the developer has predefined these patterns, they should be accessible from somewhere right? Some settings constant should be available to access these. Or would it be possible to access these through reflection?

Comment: Even if it is accessible, it won't be worth the hassle IMHO. You can just define these patterns (which, again, is essentially a collection of `long[]`s) somewhere within your app (a file, an XML resource, SharedPreferences, etc). Shouldn't be too hard, right?

Comment: I agree its not hard. I just didn't want to re-invent the wheel :D